# Gulp error: Task function must be specified

Tags: javascript, npm, gulp

This is my first time using Gulp, I am trying to make a gulpfile to minify and merge `css` and `js` files, but I have this error when I run the command `gulp`:

```
C:\Users\S.Hocine\Desktop\gulpTest>gulp
AssertionError [ERR_ASSERTION]: Task function must be specified
    at Gulp.set [as _setTask] (C:\Users\S.Hocine\Desktop\gulpTest\node_modules\undertaker\lib\set-task.js:10:3)
    at Gulp.task (C:\Users\S.Hocine\Desktop\gulpTest\node_modules\undertaker\lib\task.js:13:8)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\S.Hocine\Desktop\gulpTest\gulpfile.js:36:6)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1156:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1176:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1000:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:899:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1042:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:77:18)
    at requireOrImport (C:\Users\S.Hocine\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\gulp-cli\lib\shared\require-or-import.js:19:11) {
  generatedMessage: false,
  code: 'ERR_ASSERTION',
  actual: false,
  expected: true,
  operator: '=='
}
```

my gulpfile:

```
const gulp = require('gulp');
const uglify = require('gulp-uglify');
const concat = require('gulp-concat');

// minify and copy html
gulp.task('minifyHtml', function(){
    gulp.src('src/*.html')
        .pipe(uglify())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dest'));
  });

// minify and merge css
gulp.task('minifyMergeCss', function(){
    gulp.src('src/css/*.css')
        .pipe(concat('merged-min.css'))
        .pipe(uglify())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dest/css'));
  });

// minify and merge js
gulp.task('minifyMergeJs', function(){
  gulp.src('src/js/*.js')
      .pipe(concat('merged-min.js'))
      .pipe(uglify())
      .pipe(gulp.dest('dest/js'));
});

gulp.task('default', ['minifyHtml', 'minifyMergeCss', 'minifyMergeJs']);

gulp.task('watch', function(){
  gulp.watch('src/*.html', ['minifyHtml']);  
  gulp.watch('src/css/*.css', ['minifyMergeCss']);
  gulp.watch('src/js/*.js', ['minifyMergeJs']);
});
```

my gulp version:
CLI version: 2.3.0
Local version: 4.0.2

Where is the problem ?

Comment: Change to this: gulp.task('default', gulp.series('minifyHtml', 'minifyMergeCss', 'minifyMergeJs'));  and the same for your three `gulp.watch` statements.  E.g., gulp.watch('src/*.html', gulp.series('minifyHtml'));  You used gulp v3 syntax - I changed to gulpv4 syntax.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you uses the gulp version V3 that contain the different syntax use the latest version of gulp, and also for gulp task modules that you are using into latest version if that doesn't work too use this way,

```
An example of your function it must be,

    gulp.task('default', gulp.series('minifyHtml', 'minifyMergeCss', 'minifyMergeJs'));
```

Now that'll work fine. This happens because of in gulp v4 the list parameter has been deprecated.

see the more robust example in the  [gulp documentation for running tasks in series](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/recipes/running-tasks-in-series.md)

or you can see the documentation [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/)

Comment: Could you elaborate more and give a more full example? I don't understand how the source of OP concretely should be changed.